# power analysis for glmer mixed models

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, statistical-power

I want to know an appropriate way to conduct a post-hoc power analysis for several glmer models built in R using the lme4 package. A reviewer asked for this.

*What I did:*

- I used the R package simr which conducts power analyses for mixed-effects models using simulation. However, the resulting post-hoc power was around 98%, which seems inflated/inaccurate.

*Question:*

Could you suggest a way to accurately run a post-hoc power analysis for glmer models?

Comment: Most recommendations advice strictly against all post-hoc power analyses, so I don't think there is a good way. Maybe try to find a simulation study on power / sample size recommendation in glmer models and refer to that (if it suggests your sample was adequately powered).

Comment: @Sointu Thank you so much for your informative reply. This helped a lot!